# Swift 3 / Xcode 8 - Como mudar o idioma nativo do meu App?

Tags: swift

Estou finalizando uma aplicação e não pude deixar de perceber que alguns componentes do meu app estão em inglês:

[image: Itens de contexto]

[image: Edit action do meu tableview]

Como mudar o idioma nativo do app? 
Como fazê-lo trocar automaticamente de acordo com o idioma do meu aparelho?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para isso, você deve usar adicionar o Português como idioma no seu projeto.

Por padrão, o idioma base é Inglês. Para adicionar mais um idioma, vá em:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. Acesse seu .xcodeproject;
2. No canto superior esquerdo, escolha seu projeto ao invés de seu target;
3. Em "Localizations", adicione o idioma em questão.

Ao fazer isso, o Xcode te dá opção de traduzir todos os documentos do seu projeto (aplicáveis, geralmente .string, .xib e .storyboard).

Caso adicione um arquivo depois de configurar o novo idioma e queira incluí-lo no *Localizations* também, você deve acessar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Clique em "Localize..."

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5. Adicione o idioma que falta.

Se você estiver usando Português como idioma no seu aparelho, isso fará com que o iOS "traduza" os componentes do sistema em seu aplicativo.

Para saber mais sobre *Internationalization*, aqui vai um tutorial muito bom do Ray Wenderlich: https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Answer (score 5):

Para mudar somente o idioma base, acesse a pasta onde está localizado seu projeto e abra o conteúdo do pacote do projeto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Em seguida, abra o arquivo ***project.pbxproj*** com o Editor de texto. Feito isso, dê um *Command+F* e procure por "English". Agora ficou fácil, basta alterar o **English** por **Portuguese** e o **en** por **pt**:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Lembrando que dessa forma você estará alterando o Development Language do seu app para o Português Brasileiro.